# Coloring HTML Table Borders On Hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the top and bottom border of a `tr` to change colour when I hover over it. The problem that I am having is that the `tr` above the hovering one is overriding the hover styles (at least that is what I think is happening).

In my example here, the first item is hovering correctly, but in the second and third ones only the bottom border is highlighting:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

table tr:hover td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>COMPANY</th>
    <th>CONTACT</th>
    <th>COUNTRY</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are collapsing the borders but still want to see them?

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse` has an [intricate algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution) for deciding which border is shown.

Comment: Collapsed borders have rules to determine which border is the one that is shown. Try `border-spacing:0` instead of `border-collapse` and see if that's any better for you.

Comment: Ok I understand. `border-spacing: 0` leaves you with quite an ugly table though so that still sucks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep your 2 px borders, you need to get rid of the collapse and then remove the border-padding.  You can then use a sibling selector to change the correct borders on hover.

In the below, I have just added a thead and tbody to your table so that we know only the body elements will change when hovered

```css
table {
 border-spacing:0;
}

th {
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

td {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 214, 214); /* make all cells have a top border */
}

tbody tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);  /* make the last row also have a bottom border */ 
}

tbody tr:hover td {
  border-color: red;    /* change all borders to red on hover (mainly because of the last child bottom border */
}

tbody tr:hover + tr td {
  border-top-color: red;  /* change any cells without a bottom border - make the next row have top border go red (so it looks like current row bottom border) */
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>COMPANY</th>
    <th>CONTACT</th>
    <th>COUNTRY</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Insane solution man! Well done and thank you! Would you mind explaining that last class please `tbody tr:hover + tr td`? I don't fully understand how css changes something else

Comment: I don't think you need to use the tbody and thead here

Comment: Hi @Frank the tbody isn't really needed but it's just to make sure if you had any normal td cells in the header, they wouldn't get styled. The selector basically says select the td of any tr that is the direct next sibling (the plus means the next sibling) of the tr that is hovered

Comment: Ah I see! Well that you for the answer and teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I can get when not using collapse which is what your issue was

- border-spacing:0;
- border-top/bottom: 1px instead of 2px

```css
table {
   border-spacing:0;
}

th {
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

table tr:hover td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>COMPANY</th>
    <th>CONTACT</th>
    <th>COUNTRY</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I understand why this works, but I wish there was a different answer though

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `border-collapse: collapse;` and add `border-spacing:0`

Answer (score 0):

another option "could" be to use :before or :after !

One of the main benefits is that it is not going to change the size of the box like border does.

Here is an example of it:

```
table tr {
    position: relative;
}

table tr:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
}
```

The "content" attribute is mandatory to be able to generate the element but the string can be empty (especially when you want to use this element as a graphic hack).

EDIT — I forgot to precise you the hover state:

```
table tr:hover:before {
    background: blue;
}
```

NOTE — :before is automatically placed right before the content of the parent while :after is placed right after (before the parent's tag is closed).